# WPF dynamic number line chart

Tags: c#, wpf, charts, linechart

Hy,

I need a line chart but I know the number of charts only during the runtime and the graph should change dynamicly so if I get new data the graph should update. Additional if I get higher values than the current size of the graph should change to show the higher values. I want to update the graph every second. How can I accomplish this in WPF and what would be the best solution?

Best regards

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use OxyPlot . it is very usefull library
find it in the link below [OxyPlot codePlex](http://oxyplot.codeplex.com/)

Comment: Hy, I used OxyPlot. The following site helped me a lot

http://blog.bartdemeyer.be/2013/03/creating-graphs-in-wpf-using-oxyplot/

Answer (score 1):

It can be done by using default WPF Toolkit charts. Though they are very slow and maybe the OxyPlot library from another answer would be a better idea.

As to your questions,

> the graph should change dynamicly so if I get new data the graph should update

You can achieve this by using data binding and the `ObservableCollection` class. I answered how to do this here: [WPF Chart Series Dynamic Databinding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3631294/wpf-chart-series-dynamic-databinding/3631632#3631632)

> if I get higher values than the current size of the graph should change to show the higher values.

It will work by default in WPF Toolkit charts if your don't set the `Maximum` property of your Y-axis.

> I know the number of charts only during the runtime

It is the most complex part, because you will need to extend the `Chart` class. I have written [an article how to do this for Silverlight and WPF Toolkit charts](http://vortexwolf.wordpress.com/2011/04/04/silverlight-chart-multiple-series-databinding/), also you can download an example directly [from here](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/8047386/WordPress/WpfBindableChart.zip).